# Determine a function $f(x)$ such that $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(3-4 y^2\right) e^{-y^2} f(x-y) d y=e^{-x^2}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: fourier-transform

Determine a function $f(x)$ such that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(3-4 y^2\right) e^{-y^2} f(x-y) d y=e^{-x^2}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

I know that we are using Fourier transform but could someone please explain that how could we get this as stated in the solution. And also why the solution switched the y into x?

After Fourier transformation, the equation takes the form
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[\left(3-4 x^2\right) e^{-x^2}\right](\xi) \hat{f}(\xi)=\mathcal{F}\left[e^{-x^2}\right](\xi)
$$

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Are you familiar with convolution? Also hint: $3-4x^2 = 1 - (4x^2-2)$

Comment: Is this what you mean? $g * f(x)=f * g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(3-4 y^2\right) e^{-y^2} f(x-y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[1-\left(4(x-y)^2-2\right)\right] f(y) d y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the Fourier transform, $F(k)$, of $f(x)$ as

$$F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx$$

Then, using the convolution theorem we find that

$$\begin{align}
F(k)&=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{ikx}\,dx}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty (3-4x^2)e^{-x^2}e^{ikx}\,dx}\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi e^{-k^2/4}}{\sqrt\pi (k^2+1) e^{-k^2/4}}\\\\
&=\frac1{k^2+1}
\end{align}$$

Taking the inverse Fourier transform, yields

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)e^{-ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ikx}}{k^2+1}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac12 e^{-|x|}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you so much! If I understood correctly, your second equation means this? $\mathcal{F}(f * g(x))=\hat{f} \hat{g} \Rightarrow \hat{f}=\frac{\mathcal{F}(f * g(x)}{\hat{g}}$.